# SQL Server 2005 Performance Counters Missing

Tags: sql-server, performance-counters

I wanted to do some performance monitoring on one of our blade servers here at the bank., but ran into a little stumbling block.  When trying to create a pretty standard counter log, via performance manger, I noticed that the SQL Server object does not exist for available counters.  Pretty strange.

High level SQL Server specs:

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4053.00 (X64) (Service Pack 3) Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Windows Server 2003) (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

I've referenced [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/03/03/troubleshooting-sql-server-2005-2008-performance-counter-collection-problems.aspx) as an FYI of a known issue I suppose.  Please let me know your thoughts.  I'd really like to track this stuff and setup a performance baseline, but that's going to be pretty challenging if I cannot even count things like:

SQLServer:BufferManager - Buffer cache hit ratio

SQLServer:BufferManager - Page life expectancy

SQLServer:GeneralStatistics - User Connections

SQLServer:MemoryManager - Memory Grants Pending

Answer (score 0):

Most often this problem occurs when using the wrong platform counters monitor app. Eg. running 64bit perfmon.exe when the SQL Server is 32bit or the other way around. You have to be careful , because processes launched from the WoW64 subsystem stay in the WoW64 (eg. if you're running 32bit cmd.exe and type perfmon, then it will launch the 32bit perfmon.exe). Since you say that SQL Server itself is 64bit, it would seem that you're somehow launching the monitoring tools from the WoW64 subsystem (Visual Studio perhaps?). Make sure you launch the 64bit perfmon (or logman.exe).

Comment: Thank you Remus, although I don't think this issue applies in my case.  I'm actually connecting to the Server itself, via RDP, and trying to do this natively in the Server's Performance Monitor.  So I don't see how there could be a situation where one thing is 32 bit and the other 64 bit.  Everything is 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess I have to answer my own question here, or rather, reference another URL that has instructions on how to handle this issue that worked very nicely for me.  If you are having this issue please see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/john_daskalakis/archive/2009/05/07/9593110.aspx.

Very simple, concise, intuitive, and best of all: worked.

Ciao.